# How to CameraCaptureTask and PhotoChooserTask on the same screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my phone there is an app called PhotoFunia and it has a option to take picture. Whenever I take picture it shows me a page like given in below image:
[image]

I'm wondering which is this control which is giving Gallery and Camera on the same screen? I have used `CameraCaptureTask` and `PhotoChooserTask` separately but the this app is using both control on the same page. So please can anyone tell me whether it is a custom control or default.  Is it a hidden application bar and showing when a `PhotoChooserTask` is launched?

I want to implement the similar concept in my application so then whenever a user want to take a picture in application then he can take it from the single screen rather then launching the `PhotoChooserTask` or `CameraCaptureTask` separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is is the `PhotoChooserTask` with the `ShowCamera` property set to true, which enables the user to select an existing photo or take a new one.